# Getting data from URL and prevening automatic redirecting (add-on SDK Mozilla)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I am writing a Firefox add on that will alert the user when they navigate to a specific page.  The "notification pages" are added/removed by the user by typing the following command into the their browser URL:

```
YerinPrd://add(website1.com, www.website2.net, http://website3.org)
```

However, when I type this into the browser, the browser recognizes that it is an invalid URL and automatically tries to search  (in the default search engine).  So, when I have something like:

```
require("sdk/tabs").on("ready", function(tab) {
    var url = tab.url.toLowerCase();
}
```

The URL variable reads

```
http://google.com?asdfasdfasdfadsfadf
```

instead of

```
YerinPRd://add(....)
```

Is there anyway around this?  I like this method for i/o because it's very simple and elegant (I stole it from how Chrome works) and would rather not change it

Answer (score 1):

Well it's caused by unrecognized protocol. You would have to register your own protocol or use the already created ones. If you really would like to use your own one, try using [this community library](https://github.com/Gozala/jetpack-protocol). There is a folder with examples there, hope it helps.